# SSIS Performance Counters

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I have been preparing for 70463 MS examination and I came across few questions on the net which seems to be having incorrect answers. Below are the questions.

```
You have a server named SQL1 that has SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) installed. SQL1 has eight CPUs, 8 GB of RAM, RAID-10 storage, and a 10-gigabit
Ethernet connection.
A package named Package1 runs on SQL1. Package1 contains 10 data tasks. Package1 queries 3 GB of data from the source system.
You review the performance statistics on SQL1 and discover that Package1 executes slower than expected.
You need to identify the problem that is causing Package1 to execute slowly.
Which performance monitor counter data should you review?
```

- Processor\% Idle Time
- **Processor\% User Time**
- Memory\Pages/sec
- SQLServer:SSIS Pipeline 10.0:Buffers in use

Another set of options are:

- SQLServer:SSIS Pipeline 10.0:Buffers in use
- **Processor\% Idle Time**
- SQLServer:SSIS Pipeline 10.0:Buffers spooled
- SQLServer:SSIS Pipeline 10.0:Private buffer memory

I have highlighted the answer as per the reference mentioned below. As per me the answer should be Buffer in use option. Can anyone please shed some light if other wise.

https://www.briefmenow.org/microsoft/which-performance-monitor-counter-data-should-you-review/ 
https://www.examtopics.com/exams/microsoft/70-463/view/37/

Comment: I think they are counting on the SSIS package having default buffer settings and that that should be fine. The default buffer size in SSIS is 10 Mb and 10000 rows. Transfering 3 Gb with the default buffer settings shouldn't be a problem. So I get that one would check the buffers in use, but assuming they are default, CPU should be checked first.

Comment: Thanks for the direction to think upon @MagnusLander